# CakePHP Echoing HTML from Database

Tags: html, cakephp, echo

I've been trying to echo html already created by the user (Using TinyMCE) into another page in the application. The problem I keep running into is the tags are echoed into their HTML equivalents (e.g. `&gt;` instead of `<`) so they show up on the page instead of effecting the markup.

How do I get CakePHP to display the content as HTML instead of just echoing it?

Comment: As a note, this is generally a very bad idea, since allowing users to input arbitrary HTML that gets displayed is the basis of XSS attacks.

Comment: You should show the code you use to echo the content. Helper functions generally have an `escape => false` option.

Comment: @Wooble Normally I would fear XSS attacks, but the input comes from trusted users and is displayed only to other trusted users. In future versions, I will filter out <script> tags and the like in the beforeFilter.

Comment: @Juhana I am just using an `echo` statement in the view. I tried to find a relevant helper method, but I could not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

```
echo html_entity_decode($theirHTML);
```

Comment: That did it! It's weird, I tried this before and it didn't work. Thanks so much!